# What would be the best test case format?

Tags: testcase

I would like to know what would be the best format for writing test cases
The current format which I am using is as follows:
It includes:

- Objective
- Input
- pre conditions
- process
- expected result
- actual result

Please suggest if its ok or can it be improved or please share any other format.

Comment: I think it would be beneficial if we have more information about your testing activity. What is the purpose of your testing?

Comment: There is no single best format. This is very specific to your area of testing, your organisational needs, your tooling support and so on.

Comment: Agreed. This is just too broad. @ashu, if you can provide some context then people may be able to help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test case needs to be linked to User Story/Requirement ID.Linking to Use Case/Scenario is optional.

Usual columns that we used in earlier projects are

User Story ID/Description
Test Scenario[optional]
Test Case name [starts as validate that....]
Pre-requisites
Steps
Expected results
Test Case priority[High/Medium/Low]
Test Data[Optional]
Post Condition[Optional]

Actual Results[output] form part of Test Execution template. Some more columns of Test Execution Template are;
1.Test cases result [Pass/Fail/Blocked/Out of Scope/Inconclusive]
2.Tester name
3.Defect ID
4.Date of Testing